# Advertising Id taken from a library not app

Tags: android, firebase, google-advertising-id

I use a library for my app which takes **Google Advertising Id** for some reason.

*This will violate the Android Advertising Id policy*.
My question is **if I disable taking this id using the firebase metadata tag** (ignoring what will happen to the library), **am I still violating that policy**?

The tag, according to firebase doc is:

```
<meta-data 
    android:name="google_analytics_adid_collection_enabled" 
    android:value="false" />
```

I mean **how google detects that** using `getAdvertisingId` method is violating?

Comment: I used this tag in manifest and a client's app was removed by Google because of violating the Advertising ID policy. In my case I think that MoPub ads library is ignoring it and collects the ID.